# Missing message text while looping PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, concatenation, phpmailer, multiple-resultsets

This is my code:

```
// $mail->addReplyTo('noreply@pbrx.co.id', 'No Reply');
$subjectTo = explode(';', $Addres);
//var_dump($Addres);
array($subjectTo);
// var_dump(array($subjectTo));
foreach ($subjectTo as $key => $value) {
    // $mail->isSMTP();     
    $mail->Protocol = 'smtp';
    $mail->Host = '192.168.40.220';
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->From = 'noreply1@pbrx.co.id';
    $mail->FromName = 'Notes Email';
    $mail->addAddress($value);

    $subject = $supplier.' have sent NOTES FROM PO - '.$PO;
    if(substr($PO,-1)=='L'){
        $message = "Dear Purchasing,\nYou have NOTES from ".$supplier." with PO : ".$PO."\n Here the list :";               
    }else{
        $message = "Dear Merchandiser,\nYou have NOTES from ".$supplier." with PO : ".$PO."\n Here the list :";             
    }

    $nomor = 1;
    //var_dump($tbl_note->fetch_assoc());
    while ($val = $tbl_note->fetch_assoc()) {
        $message .= "\n".$nomor.". ITEM :".$val['itemdesc']." ( ".$val["matcontents"]." ) COLOR/SIZE :".$val['colorcode']."/".$val['size']." notes : ".$val['PIReason'];
        $nomor = $nomor + 1;
    }

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message ;
}
```

If I'm using just 1 address, the message show perfectly like these:

> Dear Purchasing,
>   You have NOTES from COATS REJO INDONESIA with PO : NORT170283-014950-L
>   Here the list :
>   1. ITEM :EMB THREAD  TEX 18 DRYVENT LOGO ( KXON ) COLOR/SIZE :ASPHALT GREY/SYLCO TEX 18 notes

But if I'm using multiple emails like these: `usera@email.com;userb@email.com` I get:

> Dear Purchasing,
>   You have NOTES from COATS REJO INDONESIA with PO : NORT170283-014950-L
>   Here the list :

There's no item in there at same `po`. Did I do something wrong on looping the messages?

Thank you from mickmackusa,
so i try this,
i'm change position looping my list item before foreach, and make varibale in looping my list item. and last i'm using ny variable looping inside foreach. And working.
Here the code i changed:

```
// $mail->addReplyTo('noreply@pbrx.co.id', 'No Reply');
    $subjectTo = explode(';', $Addres);
    //var_dump($Addres);
    array($subjectTo);
    // var_dump(array($subjectTo));             
        $nomor = 1;
        //var_dump($tbl_note->fetch_assoc());
        while ($val = $tbl_note->fetch_assoc()) {
            $listitem .= "\n".$nomor.". ITEM :".$val['itemdesc']." ( ".$val["matcontents"]." ) COLOR/SIZE :".$val['colorcode']."/".$val['size']." notes : ".$val['PIReason'];
            $nomor = $nomor + 1;
        }
    foreach ($subjectTo as $key => $value) {
        // $mail->isSMTP();     
        $mail->Protocol = 'smtp';
        $mail->Host = '192.168.40.220';
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = false;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->From = 'noreply1@pbrx.co.id';
        $mail->FromName = 'Notes Email';
        $mail->addAddress($value);

        $subject = $supplier.' have sent NOTES FROM PO - '.$PO;
        if(substr($PO,-1)=='L'){
            $message = "Dear Purchasing,\nYou have NOTES from ".$supplier." with PO : ".$PO."\n Here the list :";               
        }else{
            $message = "Dear Merchandiser,\nYou have NOTES from ".$supplier." with PO : ".$PO."\n Here the list :";             
        }
        $message .= $listitem;

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message ;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer. It shows how to do this kind of sending efficiently.

Comment: @Synchro : Well i try used looping my list before foreach, and then i imake variable on looping my list and used that variable inside foreach. and is work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Use `mysqli_data_seek($tbl_note,0);` before your while loop to reset the pointer when you have more than one iteration.</s>

Better practice would be to build your `list` message part from your resultset and set that text to a variable outside of your loops (I don't know where your query is -- it's not in your code) and just use that variable inside of your loop to concatenate the messages.

Comment: Well i try looping my list before inside foreach, and make variable inside that like you siad, and is work. Tq :)